# How to select from a table based on another table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join, where-clause

I Have 2 tables

Table A

```
id   ifClosed   
1       1
2       0
3       0
```

Table B

```
id     remittance
1        50.00
1        10.00
2         5.25
3         8.20
3         1.60
```

I need to do 
select all records from table b where ifClosed column is tagged as '0'

```
id     remittance
2         5.25
3         8.20
3         1.60
```

My trial:

```
select * from table B where tableA.ifclosed = '0'
```

Comment: use join between the tables

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/261/join#t=201610031431166992981

Comment: Whilst all of the answers are perfectly acceptable, this is a question that could have been easily answered via the first chapter of any beginner's text book or within the documentation on this site as mentioned by @SamSegers . I would suggest going somewhere like www.w3schools.com for this level of SQL support

Comment: @Gallus http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87678/discouraging-w3schools-as-a-resource

Comment: @Strawberry fair enough... I found it very helpful when i started out as it taught me a lot... I'm not saying it taught me everything, but it got me started along the right lines...

Comment: @Gallus - It's probably a professional rivalry kind of thing. I've got no axe to grind either way; I'm just aware that that resource tends to be frowned upon aroud here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use JOIN clause

```
SELECT tableB.*
FROM tableB JOIN tableA ON tableB.id=tableA.id
WHERE tableA.ifClosed = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic JOIN. Check out some of the gidance on [JOINS](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/joins.php)

```
select *
from TableB
inner join TableA
on TableA.id = TableB.id
where TableA.ifClosed = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
select * from TableB b
where b.Id in (select a.Id from TableA a where a.IfClosed = '0')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a left out join so that only the ids that are present in table b will be displayed . Hope this helps

SELECT tableB.*
FROM tableB LEFT OUTER JOIN tableA ON tableB.id=tableA.id
WHERE tableA.ifClosed = 0

Answer (score 0):

```
select
     *
from
     TableB
          join TableA on TableA.id = TableB.id and TableA.IfClosed = 0
```

No where clause needed

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select * from tableB, tableA 
where tableA.ifclosed = '0'
and tableA.id = tableB.id
```